# Can openssl smime -verify with sha256 certificate

Tags: php, openssl, mime, sha256, verify

I've been using the following to correctly verify S/MIME documents with SHA1 signatures, but I recently have come upon the need to do the same with SHA256 signatures as SHA1s have been shown to be insecure.

```
# openssl smime -verify -noverify -inform SMIME -certfile cert.pem -in rawfile.txt -out verified.txt
```

Has anyone done this?  I've tried adding switches:

```
openssl sha -sha256
```

As was suggested when verifying just the digest files, but it throws an error.

Ultimately I'm looking to do this via PHP with something like [openssl_pkcs7_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-verify.php), but I've not gotten even the commandline to work, yet so I'm stumped.

This is on centOS, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that openssl is able to determine its sha256 and verify without a switch, if your version of openssl supports sha256.